# JavaScript return after an event

Tags: javascript, function, return

So say I have a function. I want it to return a value when an event is triggered, says when a button is clicked. In the function, I have `var funcStorage=this;` In the button, I have `onclick="funcStorage.return("something");"`.

First, how do I make the function wait for the click asynchrously. Second, how do I trigger the return statement like this? Also, I am a very new user and this is my first question. How do I format code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your button:

```
onclick="return MyFunction('something')"
```

your function:

```
function MyFunction(arg)
{
    //do stuff
    return true; //return false if you don't want the button action to happen
}
```

Comment: thanks, but that won't work. it has to be a function that waits for a return statement. is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean a function that waits for a return statment? This has the button action waiting on the return from the function. Are you saying you want the button action to happen then the javascript?

Comment: button action was just example. this is simplified version of what I want. say its something else, like onkeyup or something. I want the function to wait for event to trigger and then return, all asynchrously. if I set the function as a variable like a half object, can I do something like funcStorage.return("something");

Comment: and also: can you tell me how to add code and new paragraphs in text cause I am a real n00b here